# Set preserveAspectRatio of SVG in mat-icon

Tags: css, angular

I have a mat-icon with an SVG image:

```
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="getIcon()"></mat-icon>
```

The generated html looks something like this:

```
<mat-icon _ngcontent-plf-c14="" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true" ng-reflect-svg-icon="some-icon">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 288 78" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <path d="M252 1H3L37 38.5L3 76.5H252L286.5 38.5L252 1Z" fill="#3ED8C3" stroke="#1D4477" stroke-width="2"></path>
    </svg>
</mat-icon>
```

All of that is fine and dandy except for the preserveAspectRatio bit. Angular always inserts

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
```

into the SVG but I want to have

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

and I don't know how to get that.

Is there some way with HTML or CSS to change the preserveAspectRatio attribute of the generated SVG inside a mat-icon?